# Create a vector in a LOOP with more conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I have a problem a little complicate. I have two database `BD` and `BD2`. For every row in `BD` I want to search in entire `BD2` and obtain some info: `Sum, Mean, Sd` etc.
With `Sum` I succeeded to make it work, but for `Mean, Sd, Median` I want to obtain the vector and after that apply these functions.

To be clearer, here is the code. For `sum` it worked. But I want now to save in a vector the values that met the conditions and after calculate `Mean`,`Sd`,`Median`. I tried to make the vector out of the base `BD` but nothing work or is something trickie and I can't figure it out.

```
   for (i in 1:dim(BD)[1])
  
{
  
  for (j in 1:dim(BD2)[1])
    
  {
    
    if((BD$Start.Date[i]<BD2$X_TIMESTAMP[j]) && (BD2$X_TIMESTAMP[j]<BD$End.Date[i]) && (BD$Linea[i]==BD2$Linea[j]))
      
    { 
      vl = BD2$X_VALUE[j]
      BD$vec[i] = paste(BD$vec[i],vl,sep="")
      #vect = as.numeric(BD$vec[i])
      BD$Sum[i] = BD$Sum[i]+ BD2$X_VALUE[j]
      #BD$Average[i] = mean(vect)
      
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

About data I attached a photo.This is for BD.
[image]

And this is for BD2: [image]

I tried to create `vec` before the `for` sentence. But still it doesn't work.
The error is always the same: `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "vec", value = list(NULL, NULL, NULL,  : replacement has 47 rows, data has 530`

Comment: It might help if you could include some more information on the structure of your two data sets - are these data frames, or lists? Is `vec` already a variable name in BD? Maybe show the first few rows in each data frame or the output from `str()`?

Comment: I added more info.

Comment: It might help if you included what your desired output would look like: perhaps a try creating a small example (5 rows?) and show us what you hope would happen with that? The images of your data sets help, but it still isn't clear what `vec` is or should look like at the end..

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a combination of `dplyr` and `purrr` to get your summaries. You could `split()` your data.frame `BD` into a list of rows. Then you can use `purrr:map()` to work with each element of the list (i.e. row in your data) to find matches in `BD2` and calculate some statistics. After you have your stats, you can recombine back into a single data.frame with `bind_rows()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# create a small data example
BD <- data.frame(Start.Date = 1:5,
                 End.Date = 2:6,
                 Linea = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1))
BD2 <- data.frame(X_TIMESTAMP = c(1.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5),
                  X_VALUE = c(31, 4, 60, 20, -11),
                  Linea = c(1,1,1,1,1))

BD %>% 
  split(seq(nrow(.))) %>%
  map(function(BD_row_i) {
    # find the timestamps that overlap in BD2
    BD2_matches <- BD2 %>% 
      filter((BD_row_i$Start.Date < X_TIMESTAMP) &
               (BD_row_i$End.Date > X_TIMESTAMP) &
               (BD_row_i$Linea == Linea))
    
    if (nrow(BD2_matches) > 0) {
      # calculate some stats based on these matches
      BD2_matches <- BD2_matches %>%
        summarize(Sum = sum(X_VALUE),
                  Average = mean(X_VALUE),
                  Median = median(X_VALUE),
                  Sd = sd(X_VALUE))
    } else {
      # if no matches, return NAs (blank)
      BD2_matches <- BD2_matches %>%
        summarize(Sum = NA,
                  Average = NA,
                  Median = NA,
                  Sd = NA)
    }
    
    # add these statistics back to your BD_row_i data.frame
    BD_row_i <- cbind.data.frame(BD_row_i, BD2_matches)
    
    # return the updated data frame
    return(BD_row_i)
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()

  Start.Date End.Date Linea Sum Average Median       Sd
1          1        2     1  35    17.5   17.5 19.09188
2          2        3     1  60    60.0   60.0       NA
3          3        4     3  NA      NA     NA       NA
4          4        5     1 -11   -11.0  -11.0       NA
5          5        6     1  NA      NA     NA       NA
```